# Autocomplete textfield displays value when selected and not label

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a textfield autocomplete field that shows a list of full user names and email addresses as designed but when a user is selected, the user id is displayed in the field; not the name and email address.  This is the form element:

```
$form['people'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#placeholder' => t('Search by name'),
  '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'my_module.people',
];
```

This is the autocomplete handler in the controller:

```
public function handleAutocomplete(Request $request) {

  $query = $this->database->select('simplenews_subscriber', 'ss');
  $or = $query->orConditionGroup()
    ->condition('pa.address_given_name', '%' .$request->query->get('q') . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->condition('pa.address_family_name', '%' .$request->query->get('q') . '%', 'LIKE');
  $query->leftJoin('simplenews_subscriber__subscriptions', 'sss', 'sss.entity_id = ss.id');
  $query->leftJoin('profile', 'p', 'p.uid = ss.uid');
  $query->leftJoin('profile__address', 'pa', 'pa.entity_id = p.profile_id');
  $query->fields('ss', ['uid', 'mail']);
  $query->fields('pa', ['address_given_name', 'address_family_name']);
  $query->condition($or);
  $query->orderBy('address_given_name');
  $query->range(0, 10);

  $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

  $users = [];

  foreach ($results as $user) {
    $users[] = [
      'value' => $user->uid,
      'label' => $user->address_given_name . ' ' . $user->address_family_name . ' (' . $user->mail . ')',
    ];
  }

  return new JsonResponse($users);
}
```

The autocomplete textfield populates properly.  I just want the first name, last name and email address to show after a selection has been made.

Comment: You can find an idea in the forum, I also gave a small contribution: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-02-12/custom-autocomplete-fields-like#comment-12681634 I am convinced that autocomplete suffers from design flaws and I would like to use a customized version, but I don't know how to proceed. In the meantime, the technique outlined in the discussion in the forum could put you on track for a solution.

Comment: I convinced the client to change requirements to use a select with fewer values but your comment is both relevant and useful. Thank you!

Comment: I built a module for this https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_labels

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I had to create a hidden field to store the value and use a custom selectHandler applied via class.

**JavaScript File**

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  /**
   * Override drupal selectHandler function
   */
  function customSelectHandler(event, ui) {
    var valueField = $(event.target);
    if($(event.target).hasClass('MYCUSTOM-autocomplete')) {
      var valueFieldName = event.target.name+'_value';
      if($('input[name='+valueFieldName+']').length > 0) {
        valueField = $('input[name='+valueFieldName+']');
        // update the labels too
        const labels = Drupal.autocomplete.splitValues(event.target.value);
        labels.pop();
        labels.push(ui.item.label);
        event.target.value = labels.join(', ');
      }
    }
    const terms = Drupal.autocomplete.splitValues(valueField.val());
    // Remove the current input.
    terms.pop();
    // Add the selected item.
    terms.push(ui.item.value);

    valueField.val(terms.join(', '));
    // Return false to tell jQuery UI that we've filled in the value already.
    return false;
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.myCustomAutocomplete = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      // attach custom select handler to fields with class
      $('input.MYCUSTOM-autocomplete').autocomplete({
        select: customSelectHandler,
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

**Form PHP**

```
$form['my_field'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#attributes' => ['class' => ['MYCUSTOM-autocomplete'],],
  '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'mymodule.myfield_autocomplete',
);
// field value
$form['my_field_value'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
);
```

On our forms we also have an AJAX callback on the autocompleteselect event, and I've noticed the value for the hidden field is blank but the userInput on the $form_state has the value.

Problem with this is the splitValues function may not work well for the labels, since it appears to be comma-delimited. You may want to write your own to handle it. It also won't work well if using the same form twice on a page, but there may be a way to narrow down the selector on the hidden field.